# How to express membership to at least $m$ sets in a sequence of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of sets $(A_{n})$. Pick some positive integer $m$. How would you express the set of all points that belong to at least $m$ sets in the sequence $(A_{n})$? I tried toying around with combinations of $\bigcup$'s and $\bigcap$'s, but to no avail. (I was thinking about the meaning of $\limsup A_{n}$ and $\liminf A_{n}$ and trying to modify it.) Any hints, help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:
$$
\bigcup_{S \subset \mathbb{N}, |S| \geq m} \left( \bigcap_{i \in S} A_i \right)
$$

Actually, we can do this instead:
$$
\bigcup_{S \subset \mathbb{N}, |S| =m} \left( \bigcap_{i \in S} A_i \right)
$$
This works because if $x \in A_1 \cap \dots A_m \cap A_{m+1} \cap \dots A_k$ for some $k$ then it's certainly in $x \in A_1 \cap \dots A_m$, and so it will still be included in the sum even if we only include intersections of $m$ of the sets (rather than using at least $m$).
In this way, it's actually a union of only countably many sets.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I have a follow up question. Each set $S$ is, of course, countable since it is the subset of a countable set. But, is the collection of all $S$ such $|S| \geq m$ countable?

Comment: The collection of all $S$ such that $|S| >m$ is actually uncountable. However the collection of all $S$ such that $|S|=m$ is countable, and you can write it in terms of that. See edit made to answer.